# Ember.js template and full height (includes JS bin example)

Tags: css, templates, view, ember.js, height

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/ozigoh/1/ |
Source: http://jsbin.com/ozigoh/1/edit

### The problem is simple.

A full height div inside a template does not get the full height after Ember wraps a generated div around it.

What I want:

---

|||| My div should be 100% height and is 100% full height

||||

||||

||||

---

What I get after Ember wraps a view div around my full height div:

---

|||| My div should be 100%, but is not 100% since the ember view div is not set to 100% height

|

|

|

---

What should I do? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the application view's `div` added by Ember:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['full-height']
});
```

Updated Jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/ozigoh/5/edit

http://jsbin.com/ozigoh/5

Comment: However, I am facing another difficulty. I can add class names to the template, but I need to render the outlet outside of this template? I am new to Ember, maybe you have a suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand, you want the outlet to be outside the application template?

Comment: I want a master/detail view construction. Where the full-height div is the master (sidebar nav) and the detail is next to the full-height nav, and not inside.

Comment: Thank you, I just came to a solution like this. Instead I use `{{render sidebar}}{{outlet}}`